# Combine two computed properties into one

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, axios, computed-properties

I have select box and a search field to filter through my data table. I created two computed properties - first one is a category filter that gets name and id from a get call and compares values with values from another call. Second computed property is for normal table search. How can I combine these two into one property so I can apply it on the table?

Computed:

```
computed: {
  filteredTableData() {
      if (this.selectedId !== null) {
          const filtered = this.tableData.filter(d => {   
              let mediaTypeJ = this.mediaTypeId.find(x => {
              return x.ID === this.selectedId;
          });  
      return d.mediaTypeName === mediaTypeJ.name;
      });
      return filtered
      }
  return this.tableData
  },

  searchFilter() {
      return this.tableData.filter (item => {
      return 
  item.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||     
  item.level.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||      
  item.house.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
   });  
  },
 }
```

Html:

```
<tbody>       
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in filteredTableData">  
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>  
        <td>{{ item.level }}</td>  
        <td>{{ item.house }}</td>  
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  searchFilter() {
      return this.filteredTableData.filter (item => {
        return 
          item.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||     
          item.level.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase()) ||      
          item.house.toLowerCase().match(this.search.toLowerCase())
      });  
  },
```

Filter the `filteredTableData` as `searchFilter`, then use it in the template.

```
<tbody>       
    <tr v-for="(item, index) in searchFilter">  
        <td>{{ item.name }}</td>  
        <td>{{ item.level }}</td>  
        <td>{{ item.house }}</td>  
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: I am pretty new to Vue, Axios etc and I feel silly that I didn't think of that. It works! Thank you!

Comment: Keep it up! Good luck on your journey :)

Answer (score 0):

You would not combine them.  Your filter function should just consider both properties and it will trigger on either changing.  So in essence your computed filter is the combined property.